# Scalding write to JDBCSource having greater than 22 columns

Tags: scalding

Is there a way in scalding to write to a SQL table that has greater than 22 columns? The problem I am facing is as follows. I have a table which has 28 columns, each row of which I am representing using a case class. Something like

```
case class ResultsRow(field1: String, field2: Int, ... field28: String)
```

I am at the last stage, where I have a TypedPipe[ResultsRow] which I need to serialize to the DB. However, neither JDBCSource provided by scalding nor parallelai seems to support only taking tuples as input and not **case classes**. I did like to do something of the sort

```
val results: TypedPipe[ResultsRow] = getResultRows
val dbOutput: JDBCSource = JDBCSource(...)
results.write(dbOutput)
```

and I can't do

```
results
   .map { row => (row.field1, row.field2, ..., row.field28) }
   .write(dbOutput)
```

because you can't define a tuple having more than 22 fields.

Note: This prescribed on [Scalding FAQ](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#what-if-i-have-more-than-22-fields-in-my-data-set) doesn't work because it is to handle reading more than 22 fields and not serializing the same to a database

Comment: Ok. So, I figured this one out.

Turns out that though scala has a restriction on tuple size (assuming you haven't recompiled it), the cascading tuple does not. Thus you can do the following when you have more than 22 fields

`val results: TypedPipe[ResultsRow] = getResultRows;
results.unpackToPipe(new Fields("case","class","field","names"));
results.write(dbOutput)`